# mod_rewrite all to index.php in one environment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know there are a million of questions about this, but I've tried the solutions in other questions and haven't got it to work in my case. I'm trying to redirect everything to index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works in my local environment, but in my staging environment it fails and I get a 404 error. I've checked that mod_rewrite is enabled with phpinfo(). I've tried changing a few things like using ^(.*)$ instead of ^ and using /index.php instead of index.php

What else could be the problem?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Hmm, well it turns out it's not using the .htaccess. I don't get the 500 error. Odd thing - I've got a drupal site on the same server and I tried adding garbage to it's htaccess, but didn't get a 500 error either. In my local environment I do. I even tried deleting the .htaccess and it still works on my drupal site. That makes me wonder if somehow the .htaccess is being cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was a problem with the configuration of apache. Whoever set it up for the site I'm working on did it like this in the site's .conf file:

```
<Directory "/data/path/to/directory">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

  # and a bunch of rewrite rules...
</Directory>
```

The `AllowOverride None` prohibits the use of .htaccess. In our local and development environments, the directory structure is different, so this code doesn't even get applied. That's why the .htaccess was working.

To solve the problem I'll either have to change the line mentioned above to `AllowOverride All` or add another configuration for the website I'm working on like the one above that does what I wanted to do with .htaccess.

Problems like this shouldn't come up for anyone if their environments are configured appropriately, but if anyone does run into a similar situation, check the configuration of the site in apache!